# dateFromString is returning nil

Tags: ios, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I know this probelm has been discussed many times on SO, but none of the results solve my problem.
Here is the code snippet,

```
NSDateFormatter* df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[df setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSZ"];         
NSDate* date = [df dateFromString:dateTaken]; 
/* dateTaken gets its value
 from the server as 2006-01-23T20:50:27Z */
```

I hav tried adding breakpoints and checked, `dateFromString` is returning `nil`.
Once I get a date Object, I would change its format and display a different string but I am not getting a date Object itself.

What could be the issue here ?

Comment: Shouldn't the last `SSZ` be `SS'Z'`?

Comment: Talkallikar please accept and upvote my answer, if helped. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last part of the format string should be

```
SS'Z'
```

instead of

```
SSZ
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems that your formatter is wrong. It should be:
`yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'`
2006-01-23T20:50:27Z

Match it up to the string you have and there is no SSZ component.

EDIT:
After reviewing the other answer, I got nervous that mine was wrong, so I tried the following:

  `NSString* dateTaken = @"2006-01-23T20:50:27Z";

  NSDateFormatter* df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];

  [df setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SS'Z'"];

  NSDate* date = [df dateFromString:dateTaken]; //nil

  [df setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'"];

  date = [df dateFromString:dateTaken]; // Not nil`

Seems that with the string you provided, you need the 2nd format I just provided.

Comment: yeah. but the answer H2CO3 gave, was already working for me. :)

Comment: If it works, then great. You should confirm what actual output you are getting in the dateTaken string. Because if it exactly matches what you posted, then if you run the code I put above with the .SS'Z' it shouldn't be working.  I don't need to get the check, just wanted to make sure I wasn't giving the wrong answer.

Comment: Ya. sure! actually I was resolving bugs in someone else's code :P

Answer (score 0):

The retrieved format is wrong verify the format to convert